# Issues downloading Graphlab dependencies get_dependencies()

Tags: python, data-science, graphlab

I am having trouble when I try to download the dependencies needed to run `graphlab`. I do `import graphlab` I get the following:

```
ACTION REQUIRED: Dependencies libstdc++-6.dll and libgcc_s_seh-1.dll not found.

1. Ensure user account has write permission to C:\Users\DANISUAR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packages\graphlab
2. Run graphlab.get_dependencies() to download and install them.
3. Restart Python and import graphlab again.

By running the above function, you agree to the following licenses.

* libstdc++: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/license.html
* xz: http://git.tukaani.org/?p=xz.git;a=blob;f=COPYING
```

So I try to run `graphlab.get_dependencies()` and I get the following error:

```
In [2]: gl.get_dependencies()

By running this function, you agree to the following licenses.

* libstdc++: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/libstdc++/manual/license.html
* xz: http://git.tukaani.org/?p=xz.git;a=blob;f=COPYING

Downloading xz.
Extracting xz.
Downloading gcc-libs.
Extracting gcc-libs.
xz: c:\users\danisuar\appdata\local\temp\tmpcdpyzp.xz: File format not recognized
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CalledProcessError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-5349b2d86a08> in <module>()
----> 1 gl.get_dependencies()

C:\Users\DANISUAR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\site-packag
es\graphlab\dependencies.pyc in get_dependencies()
 45     prev_cwd = os.getcwd()
 46     os.chdir(dllarchive_dir)
---> 47     subprocess.check_call([xz, '-d', dllarchive_file])
 48     dllarchive_tar = tarfile.open(os.path.splitext(dllarchive_file)[0])
 49     dllarchive_tar.extractall()

C:\Users\DANISUAR\AppData\Local\Continuum\Miniconda2\envs\gl-env\lib\subprocess.pyc in check_call(*popenargs, **kwargs)
539         if cmd is None:
540             cmd = popenargs[0]
--> 541         raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
542     return 0
543

CalledProcessError: Command '['c:\\users\\danisuar\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tmpf1habd\\bin_x86-64\\xz.exe', '-d', 'c:\\users\\danisuar\\appdata\\local\\temp\\tmpcdpyzp.xz']' returned non-zero exit status 1
```

I am using an Anaconda environment with Python 2.7 and Windows 7.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The first step is to install all the graph packages using the procedures listed in [**this link**](https://turi.com/download/install-graphlab-create-command-line.html) using PIP installer.
Verify the successful installation of GraphLab by typing:

> import graphlab

The following errors may appear as given in this image:

[image]

Then, you can run `graphlab.get_dependencies()` in Python's terminal.

Verify the installation again in Python's terminal using:

> import graphlab

Comment: Please do not include screenshots of text. Copy/paste or transcribe the text into the post itself.

Answer (score 0):

GraphLab Create installation requires a Python 2.7.x environment and pip version >= 7 and Anaconda2 v4.0.0 (64-bit).
It says this on Graphlab website [link](https://turi.com/download/install-graphlab-create-command-line.html)

And also pip version <10.x, I used pip 18.x to install Graphlab, got depedency error.

Answer (score -1):

Do not open Jupyter from GraphLab Launcher instead open it from start menu and run as administrator. then find your file from localhost:8888/tree

Comment: This is about the missing dependencies and not about permission issues.