# graphlab error No module named 'dependencies'

Tags: python, machine-learning, dependencies, graphlab

I recently added graphlab to my anaconda environment and on my first import i get this error.

```
   ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
   <ipython-input-1-986a457431da> in <module>
   ----> 1 import graphlab

   ~\anaconda3\envs\final\lib\site-packages\graphlab\__init__.py in <module>
       246     _sys.modules["graphlab_util"] = graphlab.util
       247 else:
   --> 248     from dependencies import get_dependencies
       249     package_dir = _os.path.dirname(__file__)
       250     print("""

   ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dependencies'
```

[error message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5Maf.png)

I am running anaconda on my windows 10 machine. I have created a new environment of python 2.7 in anaconda then I installed graphlab-create to it from  [here](https://turi.com/) and I updated my python version later. Now when I am trying to import graphlab. I am getting this error.

Comment: ~\anaconda3\envs\final\lib\site-packages\graphlab\__init__.py in <module>
    246     _sys.modules["graphlab_util"] = graphlab.util
    247 else:
--> 248     from dependencies import get_dependencies
    249     package_dir = _os.path.dirname(__file__)
    250     print("""

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'dependencies'

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could edit your original post to include the text so that people who are kind enough to try and help don't have to look at an image to figure out what's going on.  It would also be helpful to give people some more context on what your setup is.  Mac, PC, linux?  Is this the graphlab you installed?  https://turi.com/

Comment: @MikeSandford I have updated my question please check it now

Comment: This is a tough question as I can't seem to find the GraphLab source on the internet anywhere.  I did find this SO question that seems similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38983295/issues-downloading-graphlab-dependencies-get-dependencies#39220993

Comment: In the question you pointed at graphlab is installed and maybe used from path variables but i am creating a python environment inside anaconda so i think its a virtual environment. So this is a different scenario.